# multiprocessing inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have read about the multiprocessing package and also the threading module but I am not quite sure how to use it in my case, even though I still think that I could benefit from implementing it.

I'm currently writing a pipeline that processes and scrapes a bunch of HTML files. My cleaning method iterates through all HTML files and processes them, by calling another method that extracts the data and returns a pandas data frame. The cleaning method currently waits for one file to be finished parsing, that's why I think multiprocessing would help here.

I'm not quite sure if threading or multiprocessing is the right choice but I think since the task is CPU-bound multiprocessing should be perfect

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
def get_clean_df(self):
    # iterate through all existing html files and parse them
    for filepath in glob.glob("../data/source/*/*.html"):
    # expand existing dataframe with the newly parsed result
        result = pd.concat([result, self._extract_df_from_html(filepath)])

return result
```

thanks for the help guys

Comment: Can you move your function `_extract_df_from_html` outside your class instance?

Comment: unfortunately not since I'm calling the instance and its main method in another script

Comment: So the answer is you can't since your instance cannot be shared between multi processes. If you task is CPU-bound using threading is not the right choice even if you can share memory.

Comment: and what would be the alternative

Comment: create an helper function `extract_df_from_html` outside the class which is return the cleaned dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According my comments, you can create something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import glob

def extract_df_from_html(filepath):
    # Do stuff here
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    return df

class Foo():
    def process(self):
        files = glob.glob("../data/source/*/*.html")
        with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
            result = pool.map(extract_df_from_html, files)
        self.result = pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.process()
```

Comment: can is till run the code in the main function inside my class ?

Comment: Try it. I think it's not a problem.

Comment: yes i tried it works great just messes up my code a bit though but which is a bit unfortunate

Comment: of course, it works blazing fast now really cool actually